# How can I expire a mechanical turk hit and still receive notifications?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto, mechanicalturk

When I call `expire_hit` in boto a hit is no longer available to new workers, however it also prevents worker notifications like `AssignmentSubmitted` from being sent to the application.

In my use-case I need a number of people who are willing to proceed in a short timeframe with no duplicates. This means we are recruiting more people than we need then expiring once we have enough who have consented, however we still need to know when the users who have consented finish, but we want to avoid recruiting more people than we actually need each time.

Answer (score 0):

Expiring a HIT is more of a dispose/purge operation and so it probably can't be used in the way you want. Instead of expiring it when you have too many, have you tried *extending* the HIT until you have enough? Extending allows you to add assignments to an existing HIT, and will allow you to continue to watch notifications on that HIT.

MTurk renamed `expire_hit` to `delete_hit` and `extend_hit` to `create_additional_assignments_for_hit` in its [most recent API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_DeleteHITOperation.html), so look for docs using both these terms.